# Failing to properly copy the library to Application Bundle

Tags: xcode, terminal, bundle, dylib

ALL,

I am working with the Xcode. My project contains one executable binary and couple dylibs with the inter-dependencies

In my Xcode project I successfully created an script phase to copy dylib files (all of them) inside the Application Bundle. However when I try to run the application from the Terminal - it fails.

The error I am gettting is as follows:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblibpropertypages.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug/dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblibdbwindow.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

But in the script I have the following code:

```
cp -f ~/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug/liblibpropertypages.dylib "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$TARGET_NAME.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblibpropertypages.dylib"
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/liblibpropertypages.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/liblibpropertypages.dylib "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$TARGET_NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/$PRODUCT_NAME"

cp -f ~/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug/liblibdbwindow.dylib "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$TARGET_NAME.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblibdbwindow.dylib"
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/liblibdbwindow.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/liblibdbwindow.dylib "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$TARGET_NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/$PRODUCT_NAME"
```

So the place to load the `liblibdbwindow.dylib` is changed, but the place to load `liblibpropertypages.dylib` is not. The code is exactly the same.

What am I missing?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your libraries depends on the other one, so you need to change the reference there too.

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/liblibpropertypages.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/liblibpropertypages.dylib "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$TARGET_NAME.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblibdbwindow.dylib"
```

And you'll probably want to change the IDs of those libraries as well:

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/liblibpropertypages.dylib "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$TARGET_NAME.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblibpropertypages.dylib"
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/liblibdbwindow.dylib "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$TARGET_NAME.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblibdbwindow.dylib"
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Will try that. Now I am curious - what is an ID? And what does it do?

Comment: It's a load command with which the dylib specified its own canonical path. And when linking against a dylib, that value is copied into the LOAD_DYLIB command of the linking binary. [See comment in headers here](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/master/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/mach-o/loader.h#L649-L661).